# regarding sampling a two dimensional array and let the sampling array has three-dimension shape

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

There are two numerical arrays, `train_wiggle` and `train_spike`. Both of which have shape like `(1000,101)`. Physically, they respectively represent `1000` points where each point has `101` features.

I would like to generate two corresponding random samples, `wiggle_sample` and `spike_sample` from `train_wiggle` and `train_spike` respectively.  The sample size is `10`. In specific, I want `wiggle_sample` and `spike_sample` have shape `(10,101,1)`. This is what I do

```
def generate_train_samples():
    sample_id = np.random.randint(low=0,high=999,size=10)
    input_seq = np.take(train_wiggle,sample_id,axis=0)
    output_seq = np.take(train_spike,sample_id,axis=0)
    return input_seq, output_seq # in shape: (batch_size, time_steps, feature_dim)

x,y = generate_train_samples()
```

When calling the above function, the `x` and `y` have shape `(10, 101)`, instead of (10,101,1) as I want. How to modify the code?

Comment: What does the third dimension mean in your example? I can't imagine. Having 10 samples of 101 features (ie. (10, 101) dim as samples) seems perfectly logical here.

Comment: I guess what you want is [numpy.expand_dims](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment that you might not need to worry about adding this extra dimension, but sometimes it can be helpful (e.g. when broadcasting). So you can add the dimension with [`np.expand_dims()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.random((10, 101))
>>> np.expand_dims(a, -1).shape
(10, 101, 1)
```

... or [`np.reshape()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape) which has the sometimes advantage of being a method on the array itself if you like:

```
>>> a.reshape((*a.shape, 1)).shape
(10, 101, 1)
```